# Display foreign key one time in the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a two models, posts and comments. Post PK is foreign key in Comments (one-to-many). Then I have a ViewModel with Posts and Comments.

This is my Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = db.Comments.Include(p => p.Post)
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.CommentId).ToList()
        .Select(p => new ListCommentsViewModel
        {
            Comment = p.PostComment,
            Message = p.Post.Message
        }).ToList();

    return View(model);
}
```

I will later filter on foreign key value, therefore, the value of foreign key will always be the same. How can I display it one time in the View. This is working

```
@model IEnumerable<FreePost.Viewmodels.ListCommentsViewModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
            }
```

But I want to use `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Message)` outside foreach sense the value of the foreign key Message will always be the same.

**Update**

This is my models Posts and Comments

```
 public class Post
    {
        public Post()
        {
            Vote = new HashSet<Vote>();
            Comment = new HashSet<Comment>();
        }

        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime MessageDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Vote> Vote { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Comment> Comment { get; set; }
    }

    public class Comment
    {
        public Comment() { }

        public int CommentId { get; set; }
        public string PostComment { get; set; }
        public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }

        public int PostRefId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PostRefId")]
        public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    }
```

**Update 2**

With my code I get this result in the view

```
post 1
Comment 1
post 1
Comment 2
post 1
Comment 3
```

I want to have this result (sense the post is the same FK)

```
post 1
Comment 1
Comment 2
Comment 3
```

Comment: What is post table pk feild name?

Comment: PK in posts is PostId -> public int PostId { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Try **join** in linq query

```
var model = (from p in db.Post
            join c in db.Comments on p.PostId equals c.PostId
            select new { p.Post, c.PostComment})
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.CommentId);
```

In the **view page**

```
@model IEnumerable<FreePost.Viewmodels.ListCommentsViewModel>
string post="";
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   if(post!=item.Post)
   {
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Post)
   }
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PostComment)
   post=item.Post;
}
```

**OR**

```
 var model = (from p in db.Post
            join c in db.Comments on p.PostId equals c.PostId into g
            select new { p.Post, 
            comments = g.Select(x =>x.PostComment)}).AsEnumerable()
            .Select(x => new {x.Post,comments = String.Join(",",x.PostComment)})
            .OrderByDescending(p => p.CommentId);
```

In the **view page**

```
 @model IEnumerable<FreePost.Viewmodels.ListCommentsViewModel>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Post)
       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.comments ) //All comments display in single line with splited by ",".If you want different line using split function to split the string

    }
```

Comment: This will display The post "@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Post)" only one time in the view? I can see you still have item.Post in a foreach.